# How to add new JTable with rows and columns by clicking button?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am a beginner in Java and I need help.

I want to add table with rows and columns in `JFrame` or `JPanel` when a button is clicked. How to add new table with rows and columns by clicking button?

Comment: what have you done so far..share your piece of code

Comment: It would be a more common (and less error prone) approach to add the empty table when constructing the main GUI (before the button is clicked).  When the button is clicked, either add data to the `TableModel` or create a new table model (add the data) and set it to the table.

Answer (score 0):

1. First you have to add `JButton` to frame
2. Than add `ActionListener` in button
3. than make a list when button is pressed like this

   ```
   JButton b = new JButton("Click Me");
   b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

   String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
               "Last Name",
               "Sport",
               "# of Years",
               "Vegetarian"};

   Object[][] data = {
               {"Kathy", "Smith",
                "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
               {"John", "Doe",
                "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
               {"Sue", "Black",
                "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
               {"Jane", "White",
                "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
               {"Joe", "Brown",
                "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
           };

       JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
       add(table);

   }
   });
   ```

More information on [`JButton`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) & [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html).

Comment: I "think" they want to be able to change the content of the table or add content dynamically to it